# What is the proper way of using Set property in an angular2 model

Tags: angular, typescript

In one of my models I wish to have a numbers property with unique numbers. Numbers are selectable checkboxes and I wish to use 2 way data binding with a set. What is the correct way to do it? Here's my code

Model

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public numbers: any
    ){}
}
```

Component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from "./user.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-page-user',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
})

export class PageUserComponent {
numbers: number[];
model: User;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {  
    this.model = new User(0, new Set());
    this.numbers = Array.from(new Array(10), (x,i) => i+1);

}
```

Template

```
<form role="form" #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 cell" *ngFor="let num of numbers; let i=index" >
         <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="model.numbers[i]" name="numbers">{{i}}</md-checkbox>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
{{model.numbers | json}} <!-- {"1": true, "2": true, "3": false } -->
{{model.numbers.size}} <!-- 0 -->
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: While the data seem to be saved in interpolation, when I'm trying to iterate over the set or print the size (last line above) the set appears to be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to the change even and run some custom code when the checkbox changes. e.g.

```
<md-checkbox (change)="$event.checked ? mySet.add(num) : mySet.delete(num)">...</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: This worked for me although not sure what is the difference of adding the element in template rather in component. I tried to add the element in component to keep the code in template more readable and didn't work.

Comment: it should work either way. Did you pass `$event` form the template?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `length` instead of `size`

```
{{model.numbers.length}}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZRDS7MqbSaVa4Ew9wflb?p=preview)